# Checkbox readOnly config does not prevent check/uncheck in ExtJS 3.4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have this item:

```
{
    xtype:'checkbox',
    fieldLabel:'Adjudicado',
    name:'visoradjudicado',
    id:'visoradjudicado',
    readOnly:true
}
```

But when I click on this checkbox the mark in the box appear and disappear.I want this to work like when you put readonly on a textfield,with this configuration on a textfield,you can´t click or write on it.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the disabled property to prevent a user interacting with the checkbox.

```
{
    xtype         : 'checkbox',
    fieldLabel    : 'Adjudicado',
    name          : 'visoradjudicado',
    id            : 'visoradjudicado',
    disabled      : true,
    disabledClass : '' // overwrites the default css class'x-item-disabled'
}
```

There was a bug raised against version 3 of the framework for this issue, see below link:

[Sencha Bug](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?76333-CLOSED-3.0.0-ReadOnly-Checkbox)

An explanation of the HTML issue can be found here:

[Input field ReadOnly / Disabled](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_DISABLED.html)

Comment: But I don´t want to set to disable,because it looks grey.I want it to looks normal,but when you clic it nothing happends,like textfield.

Comment: How it looks like with disabled option to true:  
http://i.imgur.com/efR9PJZ.png  
  
How I want it looks like:  
http://i.imgur.com/KPVjWLH.png

Comment: Add in a confirguration to overwrite the CSS class. `disabledClass: ''`

Comment: I have updated the answer to include this configuration

Comment: I have tried your solution,but nothing changed,it looks like disabled